# explicitly compute conditional expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Consider the probability space $\Omega = (-1,1)$ with the Borel-sigma algebra $\mathcal{B}((-1,1))$ with the uniform distribution $\mathcal{U}((-1,1))$ as probability measure. Now let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables on this space with

\begin{equation}
X(x) = \max[0,x], Y(x) = x^{2}, ~~x \in(-1,1).
\end{equation}
We have to compute $\mathbb{E}(X|Y)$ and $\mathbb{E}(Y|X)$. I don't really understand the concept of conditional expectation. How should I begin? Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P$ denote the uniform measure. [$P$ is just Lebesgue measure divided by 2]. $E(X|Y)$ can be expressed as a measurable function of $Y$, say $f(Y)$. We have to determine $f$ from the relation $EXI_{\{Y\leq t\}} =Ef(Y)I_{\{Y\leq t\}}$ for all $t \in \mathbb R$. This gives $\int_0 ^{\sqrt t} x \, dP(x)=\int_{-\sqrt t}^{\sqrt t} f(x^{2}) \, dP(x)=2\int_{0}^{\sqrt t} f(x^{2}) \, dP(x)$. Put $u=x^{2}$ in the last integral. we get $\int_{0}^{\sqrt t} f(x^{2}) \, dP(x)=\int_0^{t} f(u) \frac 1 {2\sqrt u}\, dP(u)$. Thus $\int_0 ^{\sqrt t} x \, dP(x)=2\int_0^{t} f(u) \frac 1 {2\sqrt u}\, dP(u)$ for all $t$. Now differentiate both sides with respect to $t$ to find $f$. You will get $f(t)=\frac {\sqrt t} 2$. Hence $E(X|Y)=\frac {\sqrt Y} 2$. This procedure is quite general and you can use the same method for $E(Y|X)$.

Comment: Thank you! I have difficulty with the theory of conditional expectation. Have you a good reference where I can learn from? Something with intuition behind it

Comment: can you please also compute $\mathbb{E}(Y|X)$

Comment: my Approach is the following: $\int_{1}^{t}x^{2}dx = \int_{-\sqrt{t}}^{\sqrt{t}}f(max[0,x])dx$. But now I have no idea how to proceed

Comment: @gregor The answer is $E(Y|X)=\frac 1 3 I_{X=0} +X^{2}$

Comment: is my approach correct?

Comment: @gregor the definition says $\int_A x^{2} \, dx = \int_A f(X) \, dx$ for all sets $A$ of the type $\{X \leq t\}$ i.e. of the type $\{\max \{0,x\} \leq t \}$, $t \geq 0$. Use this equation to find $f$. On the right side you will get integral over $(-1,t)$, not $(-\sqrt t , \sqrt t)$.

Comment: okay...then I get $\int_{-1}^{t}x^{2}dx = \int_{-1}^{t}f(\max[0,x])dx$. But now I have no plan how to proceed

Comment: I come to the following solution: $\frac{1}{3}t^{3} + \frac{1}{3} = g(0) + \int_{0}^{t}g(max[0,x])dx$. It Looks similar to your answer, but when I differentiate with respect to t, then I get $g(\max[0,t]) = t^{2}$. So $\frac{1}{3}$ is missing

Comment: Put $t=0$ in the equation you have derived to get $g(0)=\frac 1 3$. For $t>0$ differentiate the equation to get $g(t)=t^{2}$. Hence $g(X)=\frac 1 3$ if $X=0$ and $X^{2}$ if $X>0$. These two facts can be expressed in one equation as $g(X)=\frac I 3 I_{X=0}+X^{2}$.